# How to Call an Array that was Created Using the Split Function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, split

I am doing a programming challenge and am struggling with one question (main point is in **bold**).

Here is the challenge:

1. First, declare an array named `myArray`.
2. Great! Now populate `myArray` with two strings. Put your full name in the first string, and your Skype handle in the second.
3. Next, declare a function named `cutName`. It should take a string as an argument.
4. `cutName` should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. For example "Douglas Crockford" should be returned as `["Douglas", "Crockford"]`.
5. Make a new empty object literal named `myData`.

   Add three key-value pairs to `myData`, by following these guidelines:

   **6.1. fullName: call `cutName` on the name string stored in `myArray`.**
           6.2. skype: refer to your Skype handle in `myArray`.
           6.3. github: If you have a github handle, enter it as a string. If not, set this to null.

This was my answer:

```
var myArray = ["Arthur Philadelpho", "arthurphiladelpho"];

function cutName (myArray){return myArray.split(" "); }

var myData = {**fullname:myArray[0]**, skype:myArray[1], github:null};
```

I'm having an issue on the item 6.1.

Comment: You don't call an array, you call functions (in this case, `cutName`. You already know how to access members of an array (as you accessed the skype name); now just access the full name in the same way, and call `cutName` with that as the parameter.

Comment: Also, *split* returns an array, you need to access just one member, not the entire array.

Answer (score 0):

Call "cutName(myData.fullname)"

```js
var myArray = ["Arthur Philadelpho", "arthurphiladelpho"];

function cutName (myArray){return myArray.split(" "); } 

var myData = {fullname:myArray[0], skype:myArray[1], github:null};


console.log(cutName(myData.fullname));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: that didn't work... I still haven't fully understood the question but this advice didn't do the trick. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

You should perform the split over your name string not the whole array.

Like this:

```
myArray[0].split(" ")
```

That will return a new array with two words in it.

Here's the complete task:

```
var myArray = [];

myArray.push('Pepito Perez');
myArray.push('pepitoperez');

function cutName (str) {
  return str.split(' ');
}

var myData = {
  fullname: cutName(myArray[0]),
  skype: myArray[1],
  github: 'http://ww.github.com/...' 
}
```

There you have it, and it's not hard.

**Code Explanation**

There is a couple of thing wrong in your code:

```
/**
 * This part is fine, you are defining your initial array with two string in it.
 */
var myArray = ["Arthur Philadelpho", "arthurphiladelpho"];

/**
 * At this part you must create a function that takes an string to split it in
 * two parts and return an array with those part in it.
 * This function will return the splitted array once you call it, but in your 
 * code you never do that.
 * Also, you are taking an argument that is your original array and must be the
 * first Item of your array (your fullname), so you should call your function 
 * like this cutName(myArray[0]);, That way, you are passing the string to the 
 * function, instead of the whole array.
 * Inside the function you should split your string the way you are doing, but I
 * recomend you to change the argument name for something like 'str' for 
 * example, that way you wont get confused and won't be any change of shadowing
 * your code.
 */
function cutName (myArray){return myArray.split(" "); }

/**
 * Finally you have to call your function inside your object literal delaration
 * for the fullname key passing the first element of myArray as the function 
 * parameter like this "fullname: cutName(myArray[0])"
 */
var myData = {**fullname:myArray[0]**, skype:myArray[1], github:null};
```

Comment: thanks Dave this issue I have already solved. My new trouble is question 6.1

Comment: This line of code `fullname: cutName(myArray[0])` is the answer for the point 6.1. Take a look at the function.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer for this is:

```
var myArray = ["Arthur Philadelpho", "arthurphiladelpho"];

function cutName (nameAndSurname){ return nameAndSurname.split(" "); }

var myData = { fullName: cutName(myArray[0])[0], skype:myArray[1], github:null};
```

**Explanation**

```
cutName(myArray[0]) //=> returns ["Arthur", "Philadelpho"] as requested
cutName(myArray[0])[0] //=> access the first element on that array: "Arthur"
```

I'd suggest you to do something like this to make the code more clear:

```
var myData = {};
myData.fullName = cutName(myArray[0])[0];
myData.skype = myArray[1];
myData.github = null;
```

Comment: The point 6.1 says *"call cutName on the name string stored in myArray"*, not to store the first item in the fullname array.

Comment: @Dave Gomez

Thanks for feedback, I have learned quite a bit taking this challenge, but still wasn't able to be complete the challenge. Something still isn't being considered correct: I updated question with my new code.

Comment: @ArthurPhiladelpho I will explain your current code updating my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Hack Reactor challenge code:

```js
var myArray=[];
myArray[0]="Rakib Hossain";
myArray[1]="rakib.csit";
function cutName(){
  
}
function cutName (myArray){return myArray.split(" "); }
var myData = {};
var myData = {
  fullName: cutName(myArray[0]),
  skype: myArray[1],
  github: null 
}

Admissions.showApp();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Your code here
// This Code should work
var myArray = [];
myArray[0] = "Prince Ndu";
myArray[1] = "Prynzdacypher";
function cutName(name) {
 return name.split(" ");
}
var myInfo =  {};
myInfo.fullName = myArray[0].split(" ");
myInfo.skype = myArray[1];
myInfo.github = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
var myArray = []
myArray = (["Lynette Sandoval", "red"]);
function cutName(myArray) { return myArray.split(" "); }

var myInfo = {};

name = cutName(myArray[0]);      // calling cutname with myArray

Object.assign(myInfo, {
    fullName: name,
    favoriteColor: myArray[1],
    github: null
});
```